# ANTLR Tree Grammar and StringTemplate Code Translation

Tags: antlr, antlr3, stringtemplate

I am working on a code translation project with a sample ANTLR tree grammar as:

```
start:               ^(PROGRAM declaration+) -> program_decl_tmpl();
declaration:         class_decl | interface_decl;
class_decl:          ^(CLASS ^(ID CLASS_IDENTIFIER))
                        -> class_decl_tmpl(cid={$CLASS_IDENTIFIER.text});
```

The group template file for it looks like:

```
group My;

program_decl_tmpl() ::= <<
*WHAT?*
>>

class_decl_tmpl(cid) ::= <<
public class <cid> {}
>>
```

Based on this, I have these questions:

- Everything works fine apart from that what I should express in `WHAT?` to say that a program is simply a list of class declarations to get the final generated output?
- Is this approach **averagely** suitable for not so a high-level language?
- I have also studied [ANTLR Code Translation with String Templates](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST/Language+Translation+Using+ANTLR+and+StringTemplate), but it seems that this approach takes much advantage of interleaving code in tree grammar. Is it also possible to do it as much as possible *just* in String Templates?

**SOLUTION**, I add the solution based on what Terence proposed:

```
start:             ^(PROGRAM d+=declaration+) -> program_decl_tmpl(decls={$d});
declaration:       cd = class_decl -> decl_tmpl(decl={$cd.st})
                 | id = interface_decl -> decl_tmpl(decl={$id.st});
class_decl:        ^(CLASS ^(ID CLASS_IDENTIFIER))
                       -> class_decl_tmpl(cid={$CLASS_IDENTIFIER.text});
```

And the templates would be:

```
group My;

program_decl_tmpl(decls) ::= <<
<decls>
>>

decl_tmpl(decl) ::= <<
<decl>
>>

class_decl_tmpl(cid) ::= <<
public class <cid> {}
>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
start: ^(PROGRAM d+=declaration+) -> program_decl_tmpl(decls=$d)

WHAT? = <decls>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually, the correct form is: `decls={$d}`